# PHOTOSHOP - combining 300 PNGs with the same background

Tags: adobe-photoshop, batch

I have 300 PNG images with transparency and one background image. All have the same size.

I need to combine each of the 300 PNGs with the background and save as a new PNG. So, I need to create 300 new images created combining 1.png over the background, 2.png over the background, etc.

Is there a minimal pain method for doing this in Photoshop? I have CS5.

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's probably a couple of ways to automate the process, here's one:

1. Keep the background in the clipboard
2. Create a new Action (Should be in the same tab as History)
3. Hit the record button
4. Paste the background
5. Go to Layer -> Arrange -> Send to back
6. Hit the stop button

Now you've got a reusable action.

1. Go to File -> Automate -> Batch.
2. Make sure the Action is your new paste action.
3. Pick your source, I used Folder.
4. If you want to save it as well, supply a destination
5. Hit ok.

Comment: wow!!!! great! Fantastic! You are THE man!

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Saved me hours!

Answer (score 0):

There is a script Export Layers To Files (Fast)  has a option to use Lower Layer as Background so the exported images should b what your looking for

Link: https://github.com/jwa107/Photoshop-Export-Layers-to-Files-Fast

Comment: While this might do what the question is asking for, it's currently a link-only answer and is at risk of becoming useless if the github repository is removed.